# conditional execution of particular teststep according to result of previous request

Tags: groovy, soapui

I use SOAP UI Free.

I want to verify if previous response returns number (id) and conditionally run particular teststep.
My pseudocode below. How can I achieve this action using groovy?

How can I get response and verify if contains number and returns 200?

How can I extract this number and use it as parameter in next request

How can I compare if response is true?

**response sample (200) :**

```
523455
```

**response sample (404) :**

```
{
   "category": "BUSINESS",
   "code": "NOT_FOUND",
   "description":"Account not found",
   "httpStatus": 404
}
```

1.step GET accountId

2.step GROOVY

```
if(accountId is number and returns 200){
    extract this number from json
        run testRunner.testStep("removeAccount) for extracted number
            if(response.equals("true"){

               testRunner.runTestStep("createNewAccount")
      }
}
```

Comment: Kac, would you mind showing the response you are talking about?

Comment: Sure, request getAccount returns only number : for example 89766 or 9001 it's just only number without any curly brackets.

Comment: Please edit the question and provide the response sample.

Comment: @Rao done, I've added example response.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. But your sudo code has more steps (remove account, create new account) and You mentioned only two step in the question. Can you please clarify how many total test steps in the test case? Would you also provide the sample responses of *removeAcount*?

Answer (score 0):

1 - Use a property transfer step :

- Target the id using JSONPath (should be something like "$.id")
- Set "Set null on missing source" to true
- Store it in a custom property of your testCase (e.g. "curId")

Additionally, if you want the Http status code, you should store it with a groovy script in another custom variable using something like this :

```
curHeaders = testRunner.testCase.testSteps["Get token"].testRequest.response.getResponseHeaders()

testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("http status", curHeaders["#status#"][0])
```

2 - Using a groovy script step :
Retrieve the variables above :

```
curId = testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue("curId")
curHttpStatus = testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue("http status")
```

Test those variables and run test step "removeAccount" if true:

```
if(curId && (curHttpStatus == 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK'))
{
     removeActionTestStep = testRunner.testSteps["removeAccount"]
     removeActionTestStep.run(null, false)

}
```

Note : removeAccount test step should make reference to curId custom variable (e.g. using "${#TestCase#curId}) so it runs with this id

You can add the createAccount part after the removal using jsonSlurper

```
removeActionResultJSON = context.expand('${removeAccount#Response}')
removeActionResultJSONSlurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(removeActionResultJSON )
```

Then target where your response will make it equal true, then use another if - run statement like below.

Hope this helps,

Thomas